# $\sum_{p \le x, p \equiv 3 \bmod 10} \frac{1}{p} = \frac{1}{4} \log\log(x)+A+O(\frac{1}{\log x})$

Tags: analytic-number-theory

I wish to prove the following equality

$$\sum_{p \le x, p \equiv 3 \bmod 10} \frac{1}{p} = \frac{1}{4} \log\log(x)+A+O(\frac{1}{\log x})$$

For some constant A

Own work:
Let $$A(x) = \sum_ {p \le x} \frac{\log p}{p} $$

and let:
$a(n)= 1$, when $n$ is prime, and let $a(n)=0$ otherwise
$$\sum_{p \le x} \frac{1}{p} = \sum_{n \leq x} \frac{a(n)}{n}$$
and
$$A(x) = \sum_{n \leq x} \frac{a(n)}{n} \log n$$

If $f(t) = \frac{1}{\log t}$, and since $A(t) = 0$ for $t<2$

$$\sum_{p \le x} \frac{1}{p} = \sum_{n \leq x} \frac{A(n)}{\log x} + \int_{2}^{x} \frac{A(t)}{t\log^2 t} dt$$

I know that:

$$\sum_ {p \le x} \frac{\log p}{p} =  \log x + O(1)$$

Which can be plugged in to obtain:

$$\sum_{p \le x} \frac{1}{p} =  \frac{\log x + O(1)}{\log x} + \int_{2}^{x} \frac{\log t + R(t)}{t\log^2 t} dt$$

Which will be:

$$\sum_{p \le x} \frac{1}{p} = 1 + O(\frac{1}{\log x}) + \int_{2}^{x} \frac{1}{t\log t} dt +\int_{2}^{x} \frac{ R(t)}{t\log^2 t} dt $$

But I think, I think I didn't start correct.
I think I have to do more with $p \equiv 3 \bmod 10$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a heuristic proof.

Start with
$\sum_{p < x} \dfrac1{p}
=\ln \ln x + O(1)
$.

Then,
mod any positive integer $m$,
the primes in the
$\phi(m)$ congruence classes
$p \equiv k \bmod m$
for $(k, m) = 1, 1\le k \lt m$
are approximately equally
distributed,
so
$\sum_{p < x, p \equiv k \bmod m} \dfrac1{p}
=\dfrac1{\phi(m)}\ln \ln x + O(1)
$.

Since $\phi(10)=4$,
all you have to do is make this rigorous.

Note:
Look up "prime number races."

Comment: Can I just use the start of your proof, or do I have to prove your first statement first? And what do you mean my make this rigorous?

Comment: The first statement is known. I'm not sure about the equal distribution.